# Main.storyboard: warning: Unsupported Configuration

Tags: objective-c, storyboard

Hello I have this warning.
how can I solved this ?

Main.storyboard: warning: Unsupported Configuration: Scene is unreachable due to lack of entry points and does not have an identifier for runtime access via -instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Storyboard, select the view controller you want to load when the app launches, and make sure to select the "Is Initial View Controller" checkbox on the right.

[image: Initial view controller]

Comment: its  been marked and still had the problem . I fix this with cocapods update.

Comment: Its remove after set storyboard ID.

Answer (score 1):

This warning is comes up if an unconnected view controller exists in a scene. In the image below for example I have disconnected a segue from the button to the small view controller below it to cause the warning. During development this can be ignored as long as you keep track of the VCs you disconnected.
[image]

In the image below the warning is gone because the small view controller is now "connected" via segue.
[image]

Comment: Really do not know how it fix this - I update my cocapods and this warning gone.

Comment: To fix it you have to identify disconnected VCs. Then you have the choice to either delete them or connect them to other UI elements like buttons via segue.

Answer (score 0):

for some more information:

Any project consists of two classes, AppDelegate and ViewController.
If you open AppDelegate class you can see **UIApplicationMain**.

The `@UIApplicationMain` attribute at the top of the file designates the AppDelegate class as the entry point for the module.It is a requirement for using storyboards that your application delegate inherits from UIResponder and that it has a UIWindow property. 
it is done in info.plist.

[image]
“Main storyboard file base name” specify the name of the storyboard that must be loaded when the app starts.

The arrow pointing at the view controller from the left indicates that it is the initial view controller to be displayed for this storyboard.

sometimes when you build you get error like **"failed to load: entry point not set"**. it is clear that you not set an entry point, meaning you not set initial view controller to load.

To fix this just open Attribute inspector. Check the box : **is initial view controller.**

[image]

Even you can verify for some more details:
 https://www.raywenderlich.com/113388/storyboards-tutorial-in-ios-9-part-1